# copy sqlite index from one database to another

Tags: sqlite

I have a massive database (~800 GB) with several indexed tables. I need to copy one table (including indexes) to a new database. Copying the table itself is pretty straightforward.

```
$ sqlite3 newDB
> attach database 'oldDB.db' as oldDB
> create table newTable as select * from oldDB.oldTable
```

But I can't seem to find any information on a way to also copy over an index. Is there any way to do this? Since the tables are so large I'd really like to avoid having to re-index them.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has no mechanism to copy index contents.

If this particular table would be the majority of the data in the database, the fastest way to copy it would be to copy the database *file* and then to drop all other tables.
But otherwise, there you cannot avoid the reindex operation.

Please note that `CREATE TABLE ... AS ...` does copy only the contents of the table, but not the complete table definition (such as column types or constraints).

Answer (score 0):

Copying large table in a single transaction is not a good idea. If you really have to you should turn off journaling first (destination database):

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have stated, the index cannot be broken out. I ***suspect*** that time spent ***copying*** the database and then ***dropping a very large*** table would be longer than just -> **1.** creating the new destination database, **2.** determining the original `CREATE TABLE` statement (from the SQLITE_MASTER table of the source database) and recreating the table in the destination database. Then **3.** just `ATTACH` your destination database to the source database and `INSERT INTO destinationdb.tablename SELECT * FROM sourcedb.tablename;*` to get the copy rolling.